# WPF How to programmatically highlight (not select) items in ComboBox dropdown

Tags: wpf, combobox, highlighting

I have a dropdownlist combobox that uses an ItemTemplate to display information. When the dropdown of the combo is open, I want the user to be able to type things that I will search the data for. Then I'd like to highlight the item (and potentially scroll it into view), but NOT select it (selection in this case is expensive and should only occur when the user presses Enter once he's found the right entry).

Essentially this is how a vanilla combobox behaves and I want to do this for my templated one that searches differently.

I've have an AttachedProperty that does the searching correctly, but I can't figure how to set the highlighted item (IsHighlighted is read-only).

This is not a cosmetic issue only, since Enter should select the highlighted item.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If you can add a dependency property to the object in the list you are displaying that holds a bool value for the "ShowHighlighted" state, you could then add a trigger to your ItemTemplate that changes the Background Brush based upon the value of ShowHighlighted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not looking to change the appearance of the selected item....

Comment: ShowSelected wasn't meant to be the selected item, it is just a bool flag to indicate which item you want highlighted. Edit: I have changed the text in the answer to use a different name...